# generate incoming call graph

Tags: c#, roslyn, code-analysis

I'm trying to pretty print the method calls until a specific method

for example let's take "DisplayHelp" from this simple random repository

I expect for something like

`Shell.ctor -> GetHelp -> DisplayHelp`

```
using Broslyn; // dotnet add package Broslyn --version 1.2.0
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FindSymbols;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

var csproj = "./clisharp/clisharp.csproj"; // git clone https://github.com/citrus-thunder/clisharp
var methodName = "DisplayHelp";

var workspace = CSharpCompilationCapture.Build(csproj).Workspace;
var project = workspace.CurrentSolution.Projects.FirstOrDefault();
var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();

var targetMethod = compilation.SyntaxTrees
    .SelectMany(tree => tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>())
    .FirstOrDefault(method => method.Identifier.ValueText == methodName);

var incomingCallGraph = new Dictionary<IMethodSymbol, List<IMethodSymbol>>();
BuildIncomingCallGraph(compilation, targetMethod, incomingCallGraph);


void BuildIncomingCallGraph(Compilation compilation, MethodDeclarationSyntax targetMethodSyntax, Dictionary<IMethodSymbol, List<IMethodSymbol>> incomingCallGraph) {
    var targetMethodSymbol = compilation.GetSemanticModel(targetMethodSyntax.SyntaxTree).GetDeclaredSymbol(targetMethodSyntax) as IMethodSymbol;

    var allMethods = compilation
        .SyntaxTrees
        .SelectMany(tree => tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>())
        .Select(methodSyntax => compilation.GetSemanticModel(methodSyntax.SyntaxTree).GetDeclaredSymbol(methodSyntax) as IMethodSymbol)
        .Where(methodSymbol => methodSymbol != null);

    foreach (var _mtd in allMethods) {
        var invocations = SymbolFinder
            .FindCallersAsync(targetMethodSymbol, workspace.CurrentSolution, cancellationToken: default).Result;
        var callers = invocations
            .Select(invocation => invocation.CallingSymbol as IMethodSymbol)
            .Where(caller => caller != null);
        foreach (var caller in callers) {
            if (!incomingCallGraph.ContainsKey(targetMethodSymbol)) {
                incomingCallGraph[targetMethodSymbol] = new List<IMethodSymbol>();
            }

            incomingCallGraph[targetMethodSymbol].Add(caller);
        }
    }
}
```

Current output:

> Method: DisplayHelp   -> Caller: GetHelp   -> Caller: DisplayHelp   ->
> Caller: GetHelp   -> Caller: DisplayHelp   -> Caller: GetHelp   ->
> Caller: DisplayHelp   -> Caller: GetHelp   -> Caller: DisplayHelp

Answer (score 1):

You can easily generate a call graph with NDepend.

Just [download the free trial](https://www.ndepend.com/download), starts VisualNDepend.exe, analyze your .NET solution, search for your method in the Search panel, then right click Select methods that are using me directly or indirectly

[image: NDepend search for method]

A code query is generated here is the result, then click export to graph:

[image: NDepend code query generated]

Et voilà! You can easily change the grouping, here it is grouped by parent class:

[image: NDepend call graph]

[See the documentation here](https://www.ndepend.com/docs/visual-studio-dependency-graph#Call).

Comment: thanks but i want to do it programmatically with Roslyn